# Google Sheets - create date(YY:MM) by on row formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have multiple dates from other sheets and could find a first date and last date.
Could I use the one-row formula to create a date sequence by firstDate(C2) and lastDate(D2) in google-sheets without app-script?

[image]

Comment: from column A or standalone?

Comment: I hope it could create by C2 and D2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try if C2 and D2 are true/regular dates:

```
={"Date"; INDEX(UNIQUE(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(C2&":"&D2)), "yyyy/mm")))}
```

[image]

---

if not use:

```
={"Date"; INDEX(UNIQUE(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATE(LEFT(C2, 4), MID(C2, 5, 2), 1)&":"&
 DATE(LEFT(D2, 4), MID(D2, 5, 2), 1))), "yyyy/mm")))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(EDATE(A2,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"M"),1,0,1)),"yyyy/MM"))
```

[image]